# How to analyze the java code by using SonarQube5.3

Tags: sonarqube5.3

While analyze the code its giving the below error

```
Retrieve remote issues of project newsonarproject...
Project not found on remote SonarQube server [XXXX:newsonarproject]
Start SonarQube analysis on newsonarproject...
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.3
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid analysis mode: incremental. This mode was removed in SonarQube 5.2. Valid modes are: [preview, publish, issues]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.AbstractAnalysisMode.validate(AbstractAnalysisMode.java:59)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalMode.<init>(GlobalMode.java:33)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doBeforeStart(GlobalContainer.java:65)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:130)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:103)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:92)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:76)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 6 more
```

If any one knows about this please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin/issues/149)

Comment: In eclipse the the failing details are:   Error during execution of Sonar
Error status [command: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe -cp C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\sonar-runner-impl1185338296650411619.jar org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\sonar-project2415328033131615764.properties]: 1

Comment: I have one doubt for sonarqube5.3 is required sonnerrunner also, or sonarqube5.3 does not required sonarrunner.  if any one know about this please clarify. If sonner runner is required then where I need to configure the server details.

Answer (score 0):

Click Window->Preference in Eclipse,and find SonarQube, check the box "Force full preview instead of incremental analysis". Then you can run SonarQube again and won't get the error.

Comment: Caused by: You're not authorized to execute any SonarQube analysis. Please contact your SonarQube administrator.